# How can I make the changes to gamma made in 'Display Calibration' stay saved in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, display, calibration, gamma, app

I have lowered my gamma level within the built-in 'Display Calibration' program in Windows 10, but whenever I turn my PC off and turn it on again, or whenever I restarted my PC, the custom gamma adjustment I made doesn't get applied.

In order to get the custom gamma level back I need to open the 'Display Calibration' program itself and then exit out of it, doing this then 'wakes up' or 'reactivates' the custom gamma level that I previously created.

Is there a way where I can simply have the custom gamma level I set via the built-in 'Display Calibration' program to automatically run by default at all times?

Answer (score 0):

Not a tested answer, but an experiment that might get settings to stick: run the CPL as Administrator.

- Press,<kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *cmd* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> for the UAC dialog, to get the CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Type *dccw* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the *Display Color Calibration* CPL.

**Please let me know if that helps; if not, I'll delete this answer.**

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this advice. 

I have not tried this method yet because I wanted to ask you first that if I do try this and it doesn't work - would there be any other bad consequences that could happen to my PC?  Or is this 'dccw' in CMD as administrator safe?

Comment: No, the only consequence is that by doing this as Admin, it *might* be global (for all users). Or not.